# The mechanism that expands a double hyphen into an en-rule

Tags: tex-core

What is the mechanism that transforms `--` into `–`?
How do I use the same mechanism to transform an arbitrary sequence of
tokens into an arbitrary sequence of symbols?

Comment: It is a ligature in the font. Like the mechanism that is used for ff or fi.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I didn't copy, honest:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ;-)

Comment: I've changed the tagging.  [rules] is defined as "about drawing lines (also called rules). ..." which is not what seems to be meant, even though one could consider an en-dash a very specific "rule".  [tex-core] on the other hand is where one finds the mechanism defined.

Comment: Interesting question; some more that I'm curious about: (1) how exactly this is specified in Computer Modern, (2) some words about the equivalent in modern (OpenType) fonts -- the GSUB tables, etc, (3) how XeTeX/LuaTeX are able to bolt-on these TeX ligature behaviour to OpenType fonts.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR regarding (3): xetex does it with a teckit mapping, lualatex has a "fake" ligature definition in the lua code.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, `texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/comlig.mf`

Comment: @Toothrot Ah thanks, `ligtable "-": "-"=:oct"173";` and `ligtable oct"173": "-"=:oct"174";` (where octal 173 and 174 are en dash and em dash respectively).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, is it possible to add to or replace those fake ligature definitions in luatex?

Comment: @Toothrot probably but better ask a sensible question with more details what you are after.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, sorry my question wasn't sensible.

Comment: @Toothrot sorry sensible was the wrong word, I meant ask a new question with more details.

Answer (score 5):

This is a ligature in the font the same mechanism that changes two f to an ff ligature, so it is not under the control of TeX and you would need to adapt the font metrics.

Comment: @Toothrot it is the case for them if you use tfm fonts, for opentype xetex (and luaotfload) go to some lengths to make it seem as if what I wrote is true, see fontspec manual 3.1.8: Note the additional features accessed with Ligatures=TeX. These are not actually real
OpenType features, but additions provided by luaotfload (i.e., LuaTEX only) to emulate TEX’sE
behaviour for ASCII input of curly quotes and punctuation. In X TEX this is achieved with the
Mapping feature (see Section 1.1 on page 59) but for consistency Ligatures=TeX will perform
the same function as Mapping=tex-text.

Comment: is it possible to add to or change these rules in luatex?  if so, perhaps you could include an example in your answer?

Comment: @Toothrot answer must be yes, but if you want a reliable answer `@`-ping Ulrike under the question, she knows rather more about luaotfload than I do.....